# Python3 cx_Freeze error 'no module named gi'

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, py2exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to use cx_Freeze with a python3 programme I have written which uses Gtk. I ran `cxfreeze-quickstart` and then `python setup.py build` using the setup.py file created for me. However, I got this error: ImportError: No module named 'gi'.

This is my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
Executable('bio_gtk_programme.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='Bio Programme',
  version = '1.0',
  description = 'Bio Gtk',
  options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
  executables = executables)
```

Do I need to include 'gi' in `packages = []` or add anything to the hooks.py file?

I've also tried this with py2exe on Windows, and I get the same ImportError...

Comment: Can you also provide the script you are freezing? It doesn't have to include everything. Usually just the imports are sufficient.

Comment: Okay, so this is the first few line of my programme, @AnthonyTuininga:
`import gi`
`gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")`
`from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango`
`from Bio import Entrez, SeqIO, Medline`
`Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"` 
`from Bio.SeqUtils import GC`